# Get fullscreen keyboard in chrome (webview)

Tags: css, cordova, google-chrome, mobile, keyboard

In normal apps like for example facebook, we get a normal keyboard in portrait mode that doesn't overlap the app, whereas we get a fullscreen keyboard in landscape mode, since the keyboard would simply overlay almost the entire app anyway.

In chrome you do not get a fullscreen keyboard in landscape mode. I am working on a hybrid app. When I want to text something with my input in landscape mode the normal keyboard opens and starts overlapping only half of the app. But the other half that is still visible is pretty usable since you can't see anything with half of the screen visible.

Can you set the option to go fullscreen on the keyboard in landscape either directly in HTML/CSS/JS or somehow with Phonegap?